zip -r --filesync buffer overflow detected
I'm using a home made script to backup my files.
It's working correctly for months but since I updated from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 a few days ago, I get a buffer overflow with this script :
DATA_ROOT="/mnt/Data"
DESTINATION=$DATA_ROOT"/Backup & Maintenance/_BACKUP/Ubuntu-backup"
ZIP="kbn_home_files.zip"
# Zip & RSync
#.config/gtk-3.0 -> css title bar nemo
cd "$DESTINATION"
zip -r --filesync --symlinks "$ZIP" \
    /home/kbn/0_Shells \
    /home/kbn/Bureau \
    /home/kbn/Images \
    /home/kbn/Modèles \
    /home/kbn/Musique \
    /home/kbn/Téléchargements \
    /home/kbn/hunderbird \
    /home/kbn/Vidéos \
    /home/kbn/.config/dconf \
    /home/kbn/.config/filezilla \
    /home/kbn/.config/gtk-3.0 \
    /home/kbn/.config/libreoffice \
    /home/kbn/.config/Nextcloud \
    /home/kbn/.config/sublime-text-3 \
    /home/kbn/.epsonscan2 \
    /home/kbn/.fonts \
    /home/kbn/.local/share/gnome-shell \
    /home/kbn/.local/share/nemo \
    /home/kbn/.local/share/nemo-python \
    /home/kbn/.local/share/Nextcloud \
    /home/kbn/.mozilla \
    /home/kbn/.thunderbird \
    /home/kbn/Documents -x /home/kbn/Documents/Cloud\*

I get this :
kbn@kbn-Vivobook-S-Flip-TN3604YA-TN3604YA:/mnt/Data/Backup & Maintenance/_BACKUP/Ubuntu-backup$ DATA_ROOT="/mnt/Data"
DESTINATION=$DATA_ROOT"/Backup & Maintenance/_BACKUP/Ubuntu-backup"
    ZIP="kbn_home_files.zip"
    # Zip & RSync
    #.config/gtk-3.0 -> css title bar nemo
    cd "$DESTINATION"
    zip -r --filesync --symlinks "$ZIP" \
            /home/kbn/0_Shells \
            /home/kbn/Bureau \
            /home/kbn/Images \
            /home/kbn/Modèles \
            /home/kbn/Musique \
            /home/kbn/Téléchargements \
            /home/kbn/hunderbird \
            /home/kbn/Vidéos \
            /home/kbn/.config/dconf \
            /home/kbn/.config/filezilla \
            /home/kbn/.config/gtk-3.0 \
            /home/kbn/.config/libreoffice \
            /home/kbn/.config/Nextcloud \
            /home/kbn/.config/sublime-text-3 \
            /home/kbn/.epsonscan2 \
            /home/kbn/.fonts \
            /home/kbn/.local/share/gnome-shell \
            /home/kbn/.local/share/nemo \
            /home/kbn/Documents -x /home/kbn/Documents/Cloud\*
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated

Sorry but I'm a beginner and really don't understand what to do. I've searched about buffer overflow and zip but did not find anything to solve this.
Maybe I enlarged the buffer on Ubuntu 22.04 but it was so long ago I don't remember.
kbn@kbn-Vivobook-S-Flip-TN3604YA-TN3604YA:/mnt/Data/Backup & Maintenance/_BACKUP/Ubuntu-backup$ free -t
           total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:        15752788     5157452     1458996      170824     9663212    10595336
Échange:     2097148         256     2096892
Total:      17849936     5157708     3555888

I found this page but no success trying to use it :
zip in Ubuntu 24.04 getting buffer overflow if right single quote mark present
Thanks a lot if someone can help me to find a solution.

It is likely this variant of the bug zip fails when filenames contain unicode characters since I can reproduce it just trying to zip a file named the same as your Téléchargements

Thanks for your information. Is there another way to sync my zip file ? Or I just should zip without synchronization (if it works).

I think the simplest for your case would be to install either the older zip_3.0-12build2 (from jammy) or newer zip_3.0-14 (from the upcoming oracular release). Personally I would not install the .deb directly (as suggested in the duplicate) instead I would unpack it e.g. dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile zip_3.0-14_amd64.deb | tar xf - ./usr/bin/zip then copy the extracted ./usr/bin/zip executable to the /usr/local/bin/ directory where it will be found first assuming sensible values of PATH / secure_path

I tried dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile zip_3.0-14_amd64.deb | tar xf - ./usr/bin/zip. In ./usr/bin/zip I just find a zip file last modified 8 april 2024 wich I think isn't the extracted one but the original zip file. Is there a tutorial for this deb replacement (for extracting and sensible values of PATH / Secure_path ? Thanks a lot anyway !
